# Display car-names in mtcars where cyl=6

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R. So I need to extract the names and total number of cars from the dataset **mtcars** where cyl=6.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to store the column values in a list: x<-mtcars[mtcars[cyl]==6]

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df$cyl==6,]
```

This will gave all rows where df(mtcars)has 6 cyl

Answer (score 0):

extract the names:

```
car.names = row.names(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6,])
```

and to get the number of cars:

```
length(car.names)
```

another option would be to use the subset function:

```
cyl.6 = subset(mtcars, cyl == 6)
row.names(cyl.6)
nrow(cyl.6)
```

Comment: Can you tell me a simple thing, in this code line, car.names = row.names(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6,]) what is the significance of the comma after 6. I know it is a very silly thing to ask, but it will be very helpful for me as I'm a complete noob in R

Comment: comma separate lines from columns, writing the condition cyl==6 means that you want to filter the lines for which cyl is equal to 6. having nothing written after the comma means that you want to keep all the columns. if you add c("mpg", "cyl") or c(1,2) after the comma, then only the two first column are selected: mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6, c(1,2)]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaboration :)

Answer (score 0):

1- Filter the data frame

`subset(mtcars, cyl==6)`

2- In the data frame car names are labelled as row names.

`rownames(subset(mtcars, cyl==6))`

To Check total cars

`length(rownames(subset(mtcars, cyl==6)))`

**Result**

rownames(subset(mtcars, cyl==6))

[1] "Mazda RX4"      "Mazda RX4 Wag"  "Hornet 4 Drive" "Valiant"
[5] "Merc 280"       "Merc 280C"      "Ferrari Dino"

length(rownames(subset(mtcars, cyl==6)))

> 7